# COPY failed while using docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

Im building a express app but when i use the command `sudo docker build - < Dockerfile` i get the error `COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat package.json: file does not exist`.

This is how my proyect structure looks like:

```
.
├── build
│   ├── server.js
│   └── server.js.map
├── Dockerfile
├── esbuild.js
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── Readme.md
└── src
    ├── index.ts
    ├── navigate.ts
    ├── pages.ts
    ├── responses
    │   ├── Errors.ts
    │   └── index.ts
    └── server.ts
```

And this is my `Dockerfile` content

```
FROM node:14.0.0
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN ls -all
COPY  [ "package.json", \
    "./"]
COPY src/ ./src
RUN npm install
RUN node esbuild.js
RUN npx nodemon build/server.js
EXPOSE 3001
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve", ]
```

At the moment of run the command, im located in the root of the project.

Comment: You're sending _only_ the Dockerfile to the Docker daemon, and not any of the other files you need.  Try `docker build .` instead, which will send the entire current directory (less what's listed in `.dockerignore`).

Comment: Only running `docker build -t image:tag .` works. You can separate your first `COPY` command into two commands.